# GAE: Explain graph of instance usage

Tags: google-app-engine

- Why `Active:0`?  I am running a lot of cron jobs and tasks queue so i think `Active:1` or `Active:2` .
- `Billed Instances Estimate: 1.00` Does it mean I only have to pay for 1 instance even though I see 2 instances running, which both have requests: 700, 62.
- I see 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5 value on vertical axis. Why and how can the number of instances 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 ?

[image]

- My app.yaml is

  ```
  automatic_scaling:
    max_idle_instances: 1
    min_idle_instances: 0
    max_concurrent_requests: 80
    target_cpu_utilization: 0.9
    min_pending_latency: 500ms
  ```

How can I set the max number of instances = 1?. 
I do not want to have 2 instances because 1 instances running 24 hours will equal 24 hours (within free tier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph can be confusing - similar questions popped in my head as well at the beginning. So I watched closely the graphs and the numbers from the summary page which doing tests for more than 1 month. And compared the projections I had from those observations with the actual bill I got. I concluded that the graphs aren't very precise, I trust the numbers more. I only check the graphs to get a feeling on traffic patterns, I mostly disregard their estimates for billing purposes.

Another thing I noticed is that GAE isn't actually/aggressively killing the idle instances right away, it just stops taking them into account for billing.

As for setting the max number of instances - the capability has been recently added. From [Scaling elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements):

> **max_instances**
>
> Optional. Specify a value between 0 and 2147483647, where zero
>   disables the setting. This parameter specifies the maximum number of
>   instances for App Engine to create for this module version. This is
>   useful to limit the costs of a module.
>
> **Important**: If you use appcfg from the App Engine SDK for Python to deploy, you cannot use this parameter in your **app.yaml**. Instead,
>   set the parameter as described in [Setting Autoscaling Parameters in
>   the API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/setting-autoscaling-params-in-explorer), or by using the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch).

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using 1 instance no matter what, you might as well use [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling).

Sometimes App Engine would keep an instance alive (for a variety of reasons such as traffic prediction). You would not billed for idling instances that you did not provision (beyond the 15 minute shutdown time). Billable instances is often not the same as created or active instances. The graph is mostly used to monitor traffic not really designed for cost calculation (it's a line graph, it's hard to calculate cost from it without doing calculus). It's best to simply use your bill every cycle to track your actual usage.